# boost::asio sleep replacement?

Tags: c++, boost-asio

-> My application is time-sensitive and I was looking for a notify mechanism instead of sleep

```
 main()
 {
 boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::milliseconds(600));
    std::cout << "waking up\n";
}
```

->  Please let me know if there is a way to handle without using sleep.

Comment: Are you using C++11? If so, then look at `std::thread` etc.

Comment: @Bathsheba and what would you suggest to avoid the sleep, then?

Answer (score 4):

You should use `boost::asio::deadline_timer`: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/deadline_timer.html

```
void handler(const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
  if (!error)
  {
    // Timer expired.
  }
}

...

// Construct a timer with an absolute expiry time.
boost::asio::deadline_timer timer(io_service,
    boost::posix_time::time_from_string("2005-12-07 23:59:59.000"));

// Start an asynchronous wait.
timer.async_wait(handler);
```

Comment: ..or in case you still want to use `chrono` instead of `posix_time` for specifying timestamps: `boost::asio::basic_waitable_timer<boost::chrono::steady_clock>` .

Comment: In current versions of boost `boost::asio::basic_waitable_timer<chrono::steady_clock>` is typedefed to `boost::asio::steady_timer` making it look as clean as `deadline_timer` (which is nothing but a typedef of `boost::asio::basic_waitable_timer<boost::posix_time::ptime>`).

Comment: @ComicSansMS,DeVadder Thanks for both comments! The things you learn on SO, still worth it :)